# Looking for a system-wide autoreplace on Mac OS

Tags: macos, service, applescript, workflow, automator

I have recently moved from Windows 10 to MacOS Big Sur. On Windows, I used AutoHotkey for system-wide automatic text replacement. For example:

(alpha) would turn into α
(beta) would turn into β

Is it possible to do a similar thing using Automator on Mac? I'm not interested in app-specific settings, as I would like this to work in all apps. Not being familiar with the OS, I am struggling to figure it out, and Google/Apple Documentation have been no help!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Go to **System Preferences** > **Keyboard** > **Text** and add your substitutions, as show in the image further below.

You can get to **System Preferences** from the **Apple** menu, far left of the menu bar, or from **Spotlight** pressing the <kbd>command</kbd><kbd>space bar</kbd> *keyboard shortcut* and start typing **System Preferences**, or from the **Dock** clicking on the **System Preferences** icon, as shown below.

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn’t work in many apps, including Firefox, Office etc. Basically only Apple applications

Comment: @sheroom, Have you looked to see if there are any third-party text expander/substitution apps available? I'm sure there are some out there, as a simple Google search shows many.

Comment: If you're happy to pay, Typinator is the dog's bollocks. It has a dated looking UI, but functionally is powerful and fast. For a free option, if you don't hate Electron like the rest of the world, then QuikWord is one that is also powerful and scriptable using JavaScript. But, as I said, Electron... Another FOSS option is called aText, which I didn't really get to know that well, because the UI was worse than Typinator, and I felt like I was using Windows 95. It may have improved since.

Comment: Add to the list of the suggested apps is Keyboard Maestro which is a paid app. I use it personally mainly for that purpose.